# How do i improve the complexity of this randomized primality testing algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, primality-test

I wrote the following program which returns 1 if a number is prime and 0 if it is composite. 
Though there's a possibility of falsely identifying a composite  as prime .I want suggestions on improving(decreasing) the time complexity for the following algorithm.

```
int compute(int n)
{
    int x;
    for(int i = 1; i < 100 * sqrt(n); i++)
    {
        x = rand() % ((int)sqrt(n) + 1);
        if(x != 0 && x != 1 && x!=n)
        {
            if(n % x == 0)
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: So, you want to have a different algorithm?

Comment: Why not use a proper prime test?

Comment: Also in sqrt(n) you can just check all divisor candidates, no randomization necessary

Comment: I really fail to understand why you would try to randomize this algorithm. You are running 100 times more comparisons that the most naive approach.

Comment: The numbers i need to test are very large of order of 10^9 so i can't apply a naive approach.

Comment: @Randomizer What Samy is saying is that your algorithm is much slower than the naive deterministic algorithm (which runs in O(sqrt(N)), so it should work for 10^9)

Comment: Ok i get the point , i am using 100 times more comparisons here . But what can i change in this very same algorithm to make it work fast . If i reduce the number of checks to sqrt(n) or sqrt(n)/2 instead of 100*sqrt(n) it should work fast but the chances of false primes identification  increases so what is the optimum number of comparisons that should be used , what is the mathematics behind it ?

Comment: Just check all numbers between 2 and sqrt(n). n has a divisor in that range if and exactly if it is composite. Or in other words, it is prime if and exactly if you don't find a divisor in that range. Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division OR just use a better test as Jim suggests

Comment: I can always go by that naive approach , but i recently thought of this method to check if a number is prime,  and was curious if it could work :)

Comment: It's not a good algorithm because you linearly trade computation for the probability to determine a composite number is composite. For example if you do sqrt(n)/2 iterations, you have about probability 1/2 that you find a divisor (if there is only one in that range). If you do sqrt(n)/4 iterations, you have a probability of about 1/4 etc. You want to have a high probability even with less than c * sqrt(n) iterations (where c is a constant)

Comment: but consider this if let n be 2501 there is only 1 number which divides it 41 , by the naive approach it would take 40 operations before finding the number to be composite no more no less ,whereas this algorithm has a probability of 1/50 =0.02 to find if the number is composite for the first pass and probability of  (1/50)+((49/50)*(1/49))=0.04 for second pass and =0.08 for 3rd pass and by the time it has reached 40 th pass there is 80% probability that if the number is composite it will be identified . Please correct me if i am getting this wrong

Comment: No, the probability is 1-(49/50)^40 = 0.554 that your algorithm would find that divisor after at most 40 iterations. That's pretty bad considering the naive algorithm finds it with probability 1.

Comment: There is one thing that i am trying to implement in the algorithm ie if it has checked for a particular number and it is not divisible then that number will be removed from the sample space making it a probablity of 80%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [Miller-Rabin primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test). In this test
you use a series of "witness" values and perform some calculations.  Each witness
calculation gives a result of "composite" or "possibly prime".  If you use k witnesses
and they all give "possibly prime" results, the probability that the number is actually
composite is 1/4^k.

The runtime is O(k log^3 n), which is a substantial improvement over your O(sqrt(n))
algorithm.